# Beautifulsoup scraping Tripadvisor does not work

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tripadvisor

im a beginner with python and beautifulsoup for web scraping and i had an issue scraping Tripadvisor site for reviews like the code is not running it stays forever with  no results  . yet my code is working on other sites . Please help and here the code im using :

```py
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Hotel_Review-g295424-d302457-Reviews-Burj_Al_Arab-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html', auth=('user', 'pass'))
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you say "i had an issue scraping Tripadvisor site for reviews" we have no idea what the issue was.

Comment: my bad sorry i tried to be more specific the code is not working it stays on the run forever with no results and it works instantly on other sites

Answer (score 1):

This returns data:

```py
import requests
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Hotel_Review-g295424-d302457-Reviews-Burj_Al_Arab-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html')
print(r.text)
```

The `beautifulsoup` package is not used yet as it depends what you want to do, which is unspecified in the question.